# Should I put user info in JWT token or, just the user's ID and then select the info from the DB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, performance, jwt, token

Since user info can be changed, not by the user - but by some admin or someone else, token user info (payload) is not updated to info contained in the DB.

But I want to do how few DB requests as I can, so I think about storing the users info in their tokens.

I think that this is wrong, and I better just store their unique ID, which is index in MongoDB and a timestamp - so user wont have the same token over and over - he has to fulfil a login from the server.

But then I need to do a query to DB, and I want to make how few as I can.

Should I just query the DB with the user's ID and thats it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing an ID is probably a better idea since the user data can be modified just as you said.
Also large payload in JWT results in  extra bytes to be sent over the network for almost every network request.
In most cases you don't need the whole user data and ID will do good in most cases.
So I would recommend to store ID (may be some other field too as required) in JWT instead of all the user's data.

Answer (score 5):

If you would be happy sharing the User ID publicly with the user that is using the token then I'd include it in the JWT. However, you should not include any information in the token which the user could abuse within your system. - Such as ID that could expose underlining implementation details.

As a rule of thumb, if you'd not give the user the data that you're storing in the JWT, then don't store it in the JWT as the JWT as the user could just decode the Base64.

Also depending on how you're storing the JWT on the client side, I'd limit the amount of [sensitive data](https://jdow.io/blog/2018/01/14/owasp-top-10-application-security-risks/#a3---sensitive-data-exposure) you store as this can be accessed by any JavaScript running on the client.

https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens#web-storage-disadvantages

> Web Storage is accessible through JavaScript on the same domain so any JavaScript running on your site will have access to web storage, and because of this can be vulnerable to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: When you say "abuse with your system" that something like injections from user's input? I verify the user's input anyway.

What do you mean "not give the user the data"? Eventually I going to return the user's info.

Comment: Think about it from an attacker perspective, what could I use xxx data for? You might be using it for id enumeration etc... thus your exposing implementation details. I've seen people store some well crazy things in JWTs so I'd just be careful. Also depends where you're storing the JWT and using it as either a session cookie or in local storage. Then you might want to start encrypting data.

Comment: I do not get you. The user will receive just some bla bla, he does not has the key to decipher whats in the token..

Comment: Updated answer to include more information and links bla bla bla

Comment: @Raz  >"he does not has the key to decipher whats in the token" : that's only true if you use encrypted JWT aks JWE, the usual form of JWT is the signed JWT aka JWS which is just encoded and can be read by everyone (see https://jwt.io)

Comment: Oh OK, I am using an encryption with it.

Comment: So, actually, @RazBuchnik is using a JWE, not a JWT. I know this might sound a bit fussy, but using precise definitions, in technology, is very important. https://www.forgebox.io/view/JWTSignEncrypt

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to just send the userId, maybe token's creation & expiration date

Comment: I would advise you to send nothing in a JWT. 
This is not what a JWT is primarily for. 
Although you can add JSON to a custom claim, generally, a JWT, is used for authentication. If someone tampers with a JWT, then the response should log out the current user.